# I can't edit / create / delete files and directories in my samba share

Tags: samba

I created a samba share and mounted it to ~server.

The samba share directory is owned by "user"
The directory that I am mounting the share to is owned by "scinkpad"

I can see the files on the share from scinkpad, but I can't create files

```
  # /etc/samba/smb.conf
  # [...]
  public = yes
  path = /home/user/server
  only guest = yes
  writable = yes
  write list = user scinkpad scinorandex
  printable = no
  msdfs root = no
```

This is the samba share block in the `smb.conf`

If i run ls -ld on the directory that I am mounting the share to, I get this

```
[scinkpad ~]  ls -ld server/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Jun  5 17:32 server/
```

I have tried to `chown` the directory to no success.

This is the command I use to mount the samba share

`sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.9/fileserver server`

Comment: That should be `ls -ld ~/server`!

Comment: I'm assuming "page = /home/user/server" is a typo? You mean "path = /home/user/server"? And how are you mounting the share on the client? Edit your original question and add the cifs mount command you are using to mount the share. If you don't have a uid=scinkpad or some iteration of dir_mode in your mount command those permissions look correct.

Comment: Yes it is a typo, and i have added the cifs command i used

Comment: OK so I set -o uid=scinkpad as an option in the mount cifs command, and I was able to create directories in the samba share from my desktop (scinkpad)

But now in my file server, it doesn't have permissions to create files / directories in the new folder that i had created

Comment: Your share definition is confusing. Is your intent to have a share that is only accessible to "user", "scinkpad", and "scinorandex"? Or is this a public share that allows anyone access?

Comment: My intent is for all my computers to be able to write/read into it, my computers in the network have the users of "user",  "scinorandex" and "scinkpad"

I cannot write into the subdirectories of ~/fileserver that the server has created, via mkdir, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. There are many ways to do this the simplest in my opinion is this:

Change your share definition on the server from this:

```
  public = yes
  path = /home/user/server
  only guest = yes
  writable = yes
  write list = user scinkpad scinorandex
  printable = no
  msdfs root = no
```

To this:

```
public = yes
path = /home/user/server
writeable = yes
force user = user
```

**EDIT**: Every time I look at the change I think it will confuse people so I changed the "user" in the path to me to make it clear:

```
public = yes
path = /home/morbius/server
writeable = yes
force user = morbius
```

Save the file then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

When the client to this system connects to the share his identity will be changed to "user" ( the same "user" in the path ) on the server - for this share only. So when he adds a folder  / file it will save as owner = user and both of you will be able to edit its contents.